# I cannot find a proper Listener for my Program in Java

Tags: java, listener

I would like my program to listen a textField and users must be allowed to type only numeric characters. If a user types a nonnumeric character , program should not display that character. Whatever I did ,I couldn't deal with this. Can you help me about this ?  Here is my code

package textfieldlistener;

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
public class Components extends JFrame {

private JTextField comp1 = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField comp2 = new JTextField(20);
private JButton button1 = new JButton("Run");
private JButton button2 = new JButton("Delete");
private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private StringBuffer input1 = new StringBuffer("");
private StringBuffer input2 = new StringBuffer("");
public Components()
{

    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,10));
    panel1.add(comp1);
    panel1.add(comp2);
    panel1.add(button1);
    panel1.add(button2);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    comp1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_0 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3 ||
  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2 ||
  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_4 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_5 ||
  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_6 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_7 ||
  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_8 || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_9)
 {
  input1.append(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
  comp1.setText(input1.substring(0, input1.length()-1));

 }
else
 {
   if(input1.equals(""))
    {
      comp1.setText(""); 
     }
  else
  {

     comp1.setText(input1.substring(0, input1.length()));
  }
}


}
    });



}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Components app = new Components();
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setSize(400, 300);
    app.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you start by snipping out the code you have so far?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far so we can see what you did wrong

Comment: Sorry, i am a new user on the site. I editted my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most approripate method might be to use a `DocumentFilter`.

See...

- [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html), [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)
- And [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

If you think this might be to hard, try using a;

- [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or
- [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) instead.

You could also consider using a [Input Verifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) to validate the text when the field loses focus